# Unable to Save base64 string in the same image field by overriding the save method using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, base64

**models.py**

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    """
    Organisation model
    """
    org_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    org_code = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
    org_mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    org_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    org_address = models.JSONField(max_length=500, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='products')
    org_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_org_logo, null=True, blank=True,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    org_logo_b64 = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.org_logo:
            logo = self.org_logo.open()
            self.org_logo_b64 = base64.b64encode(logo.read())
            super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        else:
            super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need to override the save method to save the base64 data in the image field. But the org_logo should be an image field as I need to receive as file object while POST and save it as base64 in the same org_logo field and in database. Is that possible? Or it that possible to change the field name of org_logo_b64 to org_logo while performing GET operation?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It seems to be doing what you want it to do... Also why do you want to store the image as binary data in the database? It is generally unadvisable to do that.

Comment: Actually I need to return the image as binary data to the frontend, that's the reason I want to store it as binary. Can I able to get the image as file object and save it as binary in the same image field itself?